# How could I get the footprint name in Altium?

Tags: schematics, altium, footprint, library, bom

I am creating a component in such a way that in the schematic file it would be possible to change the footprint, and the component parameter "Package" will be updated.
I tried to put "=Footprint" , but it didn't work.
Someone knows who to do it?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `CurrentFootprint`.

Yeah, it's silly how the names differ; there are, I think, three different naming schemes for the same object properties, in different contexts (what's actually labeled in the Properties dialog; the name in Query language; and the inline expression or "..." macro function; and some differ between SCH and PCB, like "Part" vs. "Component", etc.).  Unfortunate, but historical baggage that can't be gotten rid of, just worked around, understood and accepted.

[image]

In the spirit of "multiple ways to do something", besides copying it manually, you can also set it in List view (SCH or PCB), or Parameter Manager; or copy the data from these spreadsheet views into a spreadsheet program and perform more intricate manipulations on them, before pasting it all back in.

Do check that other modes/views show the data correctly, whatever it is you're ultimately outputting: PCB text labels (component parameters), BOM output columns, etc.  (Footprint is an available BOM output column anyway, so this seems a bit redundant, but it should work fine either way.)